# Writing an ASCII string as binary in python

Tags: python, file, binary, fwrite

I have a ASCII string = "abcdefghijk". I want to write this to a binary file in binary format using python.

I tried following:

```
str  = "abcdefghijk"
fp = file("test.bin", "wb")
hexStr = "".join( (("\\x%s") % (x.encode("hex"))) for x in str)
fp.write(hexStr)
fp.close()
```

However, when I open the test.bin I see the following in ascii format instead of binary.

```
\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67
```

I understand it because for two slashes here ("\\x%s"). How could I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

**Update :**

Following gives me the expected result:

```
file = open("test.bin", "wb")
file.write("\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67")
file.close()
```

But how do I achieve this with "abcdef" ASCII string. ?

Comment: You *very carefully* encode the characters as hex - why are you expecting to see anything else?

Comment: What output did you expect then? I'm not sure you understood what binary mode *does*, or even what Python uses `\xhh` notation for (and it is just *syntax*, a way to produce a value, not the value itself).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I want to write "\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67" as binary to test.bin (not as ascii string). How can I do that? And finally the test.bin should be a binary file.

Comment: @aMa: all files are binary. Opening a file in text mode only enables special handling of newlines (and on Windows, causes 0x0a being interpreted as the end of the file). As such, just write `'abcd'`. On Python 3, you'd need to encode text to bytes with `str.encode('ascii')`.

Comment: @aMa: However, a binary file is *not* a sequence of hexadecimals! Some hex *editors* may *display* contents as hex, but that's just *represetation*, not the actual value in the file.

Comment: @aMa perhaps *exactly equivelent* wasnt clear enough?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You misunderstood what `\xhh` does in Python strings. Using `\x` notation in Python strings is *just syntax* to produce certain codepoints.

You can use `'\x61'` to produce a string, or you can use `'a'`; both are just two ways of saying *give me a string with a character with hexadecimal value 61, e.g. the `a` ASCII character*:

```
>>> b'\x61'
'a'
>>> b'a'
'a'
>>> b'a' == b'\x61'
True
```

The `\xhh` syntax then, is *not the value*; there is no `\` and no `x` and no `6` and `1` character in the final result.

You should *just write your bytestring*:

```
somestring = b'abcd'

with open("test.bin", "wb") as file:
    file.write(somestring.encode())
```

Note that I used bytestrings (`b'...'`) in my code examples here. 'Regular' strings are Unicode data and cannot just be written to a binary file without encoding. The `\x..` same escaping syntax works in normal literal string syntax too, but then you need to encode your string to bytes when writing:

```
somestring = '\x61bcd'  # value: 'abcd'

with open("test.bin", "wb") as file:
    file.write(somestring.encode('ascii'))
```

You certainly do not have to produce hexadecimal escapes to write binary data. Just because some binary file viewers represent data in a file as hexadecimal doesn't mean that the data is written in hexadecimal form!

Originally, this answer was written with Python 2 in mind, where the distinction between a binary and regular text file was less pronounced. There, the only difference with a file opened in text mode is that a binary file will not automatically translate `\n` newlines to the line separator standard for your platform; e.g. on Windows writing `\n` produces `\r\n` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't necessarily understand what binary/ascii is ... all files are binary in the sense that its just bits.  ascii is just a representation of some bits... 99.9999 % of file editors will display your bits as ascii if they can , and if there is no other encoding declared in the file itself ...

```
fp.write("abcd")
```

is *exactly equivelent* to

```
fp.write("\x61\x62\x63\x64")
```